# How to determine the Galois group of $x^4-x^2-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Considering $L$ as the splitting field of $x^4-x^2-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, determine the group Gal$(L/\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you need help? For example since you need a splitting field obviously you should find the 4 roots first

Comment: It seems that the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},i)$, and I can not figure out whether it is $K_4$ or $C_4$.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370978/how-to-compute-galois-group-of-x2n-xn-1-over-bbb-q?rq=1), with $n=2$, or Keith Conrad's article on Galois groups of cubics and quartics (very well explained).